# Visual Studio 2012 - no MVC project template, no 4.5

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have just installed visual studio 2012 ultimate.
In the new project dialog I have

- No .net framework 4.5 option
- No MVC project templates

I have repaired the installation. (twice now).

I have tried starting vs with

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

I have also tried

```
devenv /resetsettings
```

all to no avail !!

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled and then reinstalled and the mvc project templates & .net framework are there now.

I think the problem was that I was installing from a mounted .iso file.

For the reinstall I set my ISO software to remount at startup.

Still pretty poor that a repair did not fix this !!

Answer (score 3):

Try to install [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 update for Visual Studio 2012](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/5/6/6562AFBE-9503-4E64-970C-1427133FCD73/AspNetWebTools2012Setup.exe)

This worked for me.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time. I wasn't able to understand why I don't have these templates in VS 2012, but this was the reason! Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I thought the same when I first had my 2012, I had to manually download the file

[MVC](http://www.asp.net/downloads) [.Net 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653)

Hopefully this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks, it seems rather strange that you would have to install these!!

Comment: I thought the same! Would've thought the latest and greatest VS would have .Net 4.5 installed!

Comment: I'm trying a full reinstall !! This can't be right. Worst VS installation experience ever !!

Comment: It's after a full reinstallation that I lost the MVC templates though.