# visual studio 2012 mvc3,4 template missing after Windows update to Microsoft .net framework 4.5

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I recently installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 ultimate, because of one reason: The windows recent update to .Net framework 4.5 made my MVC 3 and 4 disappear off the New -> Website template list and only exists in New -> Project option in Visual studio 2012 Pro. I never had this before, it's only the recent "Security" updates and few others all related to .Net framework 4.5 made this magical thing to happen. I don't understand why? Before the Windows "Security" update of 4.5 I was able to see all the MVC templates (3,4) off the New -> Website Template, leaving only two Web option related to Razor 1 and Razor 2, and others few others completely unrelated to MVC.

Please don't direct me to these links, 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/efe91261-c52a-44bd-9fe7-199d86ed9733/visual-studio-2012-not-displaying-net-framework-45-or-mvc-project-templates

and [Visual Studio 2012 - no MVC project template, no 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911387/visual-studio-2012-no-mvc-project-template-no-4-5)

Because I have already tried those.

FYI: Re-installation, completely removed and re-installed a fresh copy, uninstalled all Visual studios 2008, 2010, 2012, and then re-installed one by one, and rebooted after every installation, Did not work.

Everything has to do with the Latest windows Update! Anyone else have this problem?